# How To Calculate The Average Outcome Where Multiple Events With Difference Success Rates Worth Different Amounts Happen?

Tags: probability, average

My problem revolves around an event that has a certain probability of failing. You get X attempts and your prize depends on your successes. Using this question I found here:
[Probability of rolling 3 sixes in 6 rolls](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/780535/probability-of-rolling-3-sixes-in-6-rolls)
I was able to get this far. In my example though, I have two events, with different probabilities of failing, with a different number of attempts made. I am trying to calculate the average outcome and am not sure what comes next.

Event A has a 38% chance of failing. The event happens twice. The chance of one success is 86%, the chance of two successes 39%(with rounding). A success on A is worth $10.50.

Event B has a 43% chance of failing. The event happens twice. The chance of one success is 82%, the chance of two successes is 33% (with rounding). A success on B is worth $7.50.

That leaves the following possible results:
A, B, AA, AB, BB, AAB, ABB, AABB

I'm not sure how to calculate the possibilities of each of these happening, or how to calculate the average amount of money. Thanks.

Comment: Hint: Try using $E(X+Y)$ = $E(X) + E(Y)$, where $E(X)$ denotes the expectation of a random variable X.

Comment: The answer to the original question: Probability of event A occurring twice successfully at the both attempts is $0.62\cdot0.62=0.3844\,.\;$ Event B has a probability of $0.57$ at first attempt but considering that we have two attempts it is $0.57+0.57\cdot0.43=0.8151$.
Now if we want both of successes: event A happens twice and event B occurs at least once it's $\,0.3844\cdot0.8151=0.31332444.$ 

(I could recommend a very simple book for enthusiasts who want to dabble at probability and cover elementary combinatorics really well: Probability for the Enthusiastic Beginner by David Morin)

Comment: This new question doesn't make a lot of sense to me if I get it right. Probability of success 86% and of failure 38%. That's weird.